# How to use separate images for iphone 5 and iphone 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, ios8, uiimage

I my application i'm trying to set images in imageView pragmatically. i'm using separate images for iPhone 5 and iPhone 6. What would be the suffix iPhone 6 images? as @2x is for iPhone 5 images.

Answer (score 1):

It is the same, there is @3x for Iphone 6+.

Please refer https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1

Comment: i want to know about iPhone 6. i know for iPhone 6+ we will use @3x

Comment: Well, iPhone 6 uses @2x

Answer (score 0):

@2x is not a suffix exactly for iphone5 - it's reprepresent of how much real pixel in one point in this image, so it can be used in any numbers of devices (available and new) what will have display with double density. As for iPhone 6+ (exactly 6+ for now) it use triple density display, so it used now @3x suffix.

You can do what you want programmatically - detect device and use the name you want. But @2x and @3x will be used (if available) dependently of device.